# Can "would" be used to indicate speculation and with an unless-clause?

Tags: modal-verbs

I'm wondering whether "would" can be used to indicate the speaker/writer's speculation, not necessarily counterfactuality or unlikelihood. Consider the following:

> A: Where is John now? B: He would be in the classroom. (meaning he's probably in the classroom.)

> A: Where was John an hour ago? B: He would have been in the classroom. (meaning he was probably in the classroom.)

Now, I'm wondering whether this use is compatible with an unless-clause.

> A: What was the result of the game? B: In my opinion, Peter would have won, unless he had tripped.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on your audience. I think this is fine in British English (right lads?) but to other speakers of English it has other overtones. To Americans, this structure sounds stuffy and slightly doubtful. "He would be in the classroom [,but...]", or at best, "He would [ordinarily] be in the classroom."

Comment: It is annoying to constantly read stuff re AmE that is not correct. It is not stuffy. This use of would is sophisticated regardless of which side of the pond you're on....

Comment: No. Using ***would be*** in such contexts rather than ***is*** implies the speaker is *slightly* "distancing" himself from the assertion being made, but that doesn't really have anything to do with ***speculation*** in the sense of the assertion being unlikely to be true. If the speaker intended to convey ***any level of doubt whatsoever***, he'd use ***might be / could be*** rather than ***would be / is***. In the specific cited context, it's nothing to do with where he is "normally, ordinarily" as such - it's specifically "where he is now" (so far as the speaker knows).